# Android standard icon for feedback/report by users

Tags: android, drawable, android-image, android-icons

I want to add a feature on my app to let users give a feedback on data. (for example to report errors or mistakes).

Is there a standard icon for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please, visit your `android-sdk-*` folder, there should be default set of icons and pictures in the `./platforms/android-XX/data/res/drawable-Xdpi/` where "XX" and "X" stand for your android version and screen size. all the standard icons are there.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few system icons whose filenames match 'feedback', but none of them look appropriate to me.

Best I could find is "ic_menu_report_image.png".

Answer (score 0):

I've been using "ic_menu_start_conversation.png".

Whether it’s useful for your app mainly depends on the iconset you’re already using. In a chat-app for example, this icon would be a poor choice :)

**Note:** this icon is marked as protected. You'll have to copy the images to your source manually.

> Because these resources can change between platform versions, you should not reference these icons using the Android platform resource IDs (i.e. menu icons under android.R.drawable). If you want to use any icons or other internal drawable resources, you should store a local copy of those icons or drawables in your application resources, then reference the local copy from your application code. In that way, you can maintain control over the appearance of your icons, even if the system's copy changes.